# Why is Cloudinary serving images from California to UK location?

Tags: cloudinary

I'm having a weird problem with Cloudinary. We moved over last week and found that our image load times were now significantly worse than serving the images from our AWS server. Looking into it, it appears that the images are being served from the ip address 151.101.17.137, which is in San Francisco. I'm finding that similar sized images are taking 3 times as long to load when compared with images being served from the AWS server.

So why does the CDN appear not to be working?

We've already implemented PRECONNECT as advised by Cloudinary.

Using Chrome Devtools and webpagetest.org I can see each of the Cloudinary image responses with a long ttfb and Header Response, Remote Address: 151.101.17.137

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: 151.101.17.137 seems to located in UK. https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo and https://www.iplocation.net/ 3 out pf 4 DB shows it as UK IP and doing traceroute from my side also shows routing through UK ASNs. You might want to run MTR to see if you see packet loss or high latency, mtr -r -C 100 151.101.17.137

Comment: Thanks James, looking at iplocation.net, IP2Location returns California, while ipinfo.io and DB-IP report UK. That will teach me not to scroll past the first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to James' comment above, that IP is Fastly's but the location the traffic is served from may differ based on where you're accessing it from.

Likely, the IP is part of an [Anycast network](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/glossary/anycast-network/) and served from multiple locations

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.